# How to print the information of each person and count the average age and numbers of people listed in the file

Tags: c, file, struct

I am having trouble reading into a structure from a file. I am confused about how to print the information of each person and count the average age and numbers of people listed in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
The content of the file:
John
male
19
Bill
male
20
Mary
Female
20
*/
struct person
{
    char name[50];
    char sex;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    struct person coll;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("person.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open");
        return 1;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%c %c %d",&coll.name[50],&coll.sex,&coll.age);
    printf("%c",coll.name[50]);
    printf("%c",coll.sex);
    printf("%d",coll.age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't compile right now, but it looks like you're only opening the file.  You need to loop through (each line), read the values, and print (or store).   Check this.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 fscanf(fp,"%c %c %d",&coll.name[50],&coll.sex,&coll.age);
```

to

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %c %d",coll.name,&coll.sex,&coll.age);
```

and,

```
printf("%c",coll.name[50]);
```

to

```
printf("%s\n",coll.name);
```

It is recommended to check the return value of `fscanf()` [or, for that, every library function, mostly] to ensure the successful execution.

Next, to `count the average age and numbers of people listed in the file.` you need to define an array of `struct person` and read the contents of the file using a loop. Then, as per the logic, you need to calculate the average and print that.

---

EDIT:

as per the input from the file, you should modify your structure to

```
struct person
{
    char name[50];
    char sex[7];  //to hold "male" or "female", not "m" or "f"
    int age;
};
```

and the corresponding read and print statements.

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d",coll.name,coll.sex,&coll.age);   //should check the return value ==3
```

and

```
printf("%s\n",coll.name);
printf("%s\n",coll.sex);
```

Comment: @chux yes sir, 1) because it's defined as `char sex;` 2) array of struct is kind of _go easy_ approach, right? 3) missed that, will update my answer to include that note. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given already are correct.

You are using the `"%c"` (character) specifier for the name. This should be the `"%s"` (string of characters) specifier. For more info on the specifiers see the table on this page [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/?kw=fprintf)

Note that in your file content that sex is a word and in your code a `char`. Reading the first letter should work fine but maybe not want you want to see in your terminal.

I'm not sure if `fscanf` reads over an end of line so I can't help you there. but you will need to implement some sort of loop to read the rest of the file.

My first post :-) hope it helps.